# The procedure entry point "_ZNSt7__..." could not be located in the dynamic link library. Anyway to solve without copying the .dll to every folder?

Tags: c++

I've started going through Principles and Practice using C++ 2nd edition recently and I've run into a problem with Chapter 3.

Trying to run the example

```
// Read and Write a first name
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter your first name (followed by 'enter')\n";
    string first_name;
    std::cin >> first_name;
    std::cout << "Hello, " << first_name << "\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Leads to the error:

> "The procedure entry point
> _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library"

The code compiles (Using G++) fine but running the resulting .exe throws that error. After doing a short search I've found that copying the "libstdc++-6.dll" from MinGW into the folder works to solve the issue. But I was wondering if it's possible to set it up so I don't have to copy that .dll into every folder I'm using. After some searching I thought it was to do with my PATH and having MinGW's directory come before Sys32 ([Like this](https://i.gyazo.com/c30f44da3865461c928e5b1b0272c22b.png)) but trying that did nothing.

If it helps I'm using [this verion](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BjarneStroustrup/Programming-_Principles_and_Practice_Using_Cpp/master/std_lib_facilities.hhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/BjarneStroustrup/Programming-_Principles_and_Practice_Using_Cpp/master/std_lib_facilities.h) of the std_lib_facilities.h file.

Comment: Your problem is you have the same dll but a different version in your `PATH` somewhere.  Perhaps an older version of that dll. When windows searches it looks for the first match and tries to load that. The error is that the match it found is missing a function that is needed for the current executable you are running. If you can find the dll that is conflicting you can adjust the order of the folders in the `PATH` environment variable to make the one needed higher in the list.

Comment: This can help with dll search order: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: Also if you modify a PATH environment variable you have to close all applications. You may just want to logout then back in to be sure that the cmd.exe window or IDE you are using sees the change.

Comment: drescherjm thanks. Another thing to keep in mind is there are both User vs System env variables which take precedence